# Pub/Sub to Splunk Dataflow Template - The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, splunk

I am using the Dataflow template (i've tried both the `latest` and `2020-11-02-00_RC00` of `Cloud_PubSub_to_Splunk` ) that streams data from a pubsub topic to splunk. I have followed all steps from the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-splunk).

My job arguments were:

```
JOB_NAME=pubsub-to-splunk-$USER-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%z"`
gcloud dataflow jobs run $JOB_NAME \
    --subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT>/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/<NAME> \
    --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/2020-11-02-00_RC00/Cloud_PubSub_to_Splunk \
    --max-workers 2 \
    --parameters=inputSubscription="projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/logs-export-subscription",token="<TOKEN>",url="https://<URL>:8088/services/collector/event",outputDeadletterTopic="projects/<PROJECT>/topics/splunk-pubsub-deadletter",batchCount="10",parallelism="8",disableCertificateValidation=true
```

I can successfully start the Dataflow job and streaming begins and I can see unacked message count from my `logs-export-subscription` going down, however the job fails when writing to Splunk with the following error:

**Error writing to Splunk. StatusCode: 404, content: {"text":"The requested URL was not found on this server.","code":404}, StatusMessage: Not Found**

When troubleshooting, I can successfully send a request to the Splunk endpoint from the same subnetwork that the Dataflow workers are running in.

```
curl -k https://<URL>:8088/services/collector/event -H "Authorization: Splunk <HEC TOKEN>" -d '{"event": {"field1": "hello", "field2": "world"}}'

{"text":"Success","code":0}
```

And so, I don't think it is a connection or url issue like the error message suggests.

I can reproduce the failure with curl when I remove `-d` key and value.

```
curl -k https://<IP>:8088/services/collector/event -H "Authorization: Splunk <TOKEN>" 

{"text":"The requested URL was not found on this server.","code":404}
```

**Any idea what may be causing this issue?**

Comment: Actually, it looks like Google's `com.google.cloud.teleport.splunk.HttpEventPublisher` appends the path `services/collector/event` to the IP and PORT.. The docs had requested `your-splunk-hec-url` and so I thought it required the full path.

Comment: Can you check your `custom.googleapis.com/dataflow/outbound-successful-events` metrics in the **Metrics Explorer** and share them? Also, have you created your VPC network and Firewall rules such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#about_firewall_rules)?

Comment: yes, I am now receiving successful events indicated by `outbound-successful-events`... I can confirm that the issue was `url="https://<URL>:8088/services/collector/event"` vs. `url="https://<URL>:8088`

Comment: Good ! It is documented here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#subnetwork_parameter), when you use a shared VPC you must use the complete URL. In order to further contribute to the community, I will post the answer as community wiki , ok?

Comment: The fix was not the subnetwork URL.  It was adjusting the full splunk URL to just the splunk IP and port

Comment: could you post the answer for you issue in order to further contribute to the community?

Answer (score 1):

The `Splunk HEC URL` that should be supplied should only be `https://[IP]:8088`, NOT the full path `https://[IP]:8088/services/collector/event`, as the path is appended by the Google library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. We've updated the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-splunk) with example to clarify that parameter. Specifically, Splunk HEC `url` template parameter is as follows:

```
<protocol>://<host>:<port>
```

For example: `https://splunk-hec.example.com:8088`.
Host is the FQDN (or IP) of either Splunk instance running HEC (in case of single HEC instance) or the HTTP(S) Load Balancer in front of HEC tier (in case of distributed HEC setup).

You do not specify the full HEC endpoint path. The Splunk Dataflow template currently only supports HEC JSON Object endpoint (i.e `services/collector/event`), and it appends it automatically in outgoing HTTP requests.

Also, for a deeper dive, be sure to check out these **new** resources:

- [Deploying production-ready log exports to Splunk using Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-production-ready-log-exports-to-splunk-using-dataflow): This tutorial incorporates security best practices, plus guidance on how to capacity plan the Splunk Dataflow pipeline, and how to handle potential delivery failures to avoid data loss.
- [Dataflow product documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#pubsub-to-splunk): for latest Splunk Dataflow template parameters details.